# Query returns duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql

The query below is showing some duplicate and wrong values:

```
SELECT c.contest_id, c.hacker_id, c.name,
SUM(s.total_submissions) as total_submissions,
SUM(s.total_accepted_submissions) as total_accepted_submissions,
SUM(v.total_views) as total_views,
SUM(v.total_unique_views) as total_unique_views
FROM concursos c
JOIN faculdades f ON f.contest_id = c.contest_id
JOIN desafios d ON d.college_id = f.college_id
LEFT JOIN view_stats v ON v.challenge_id = d.challenge_id
LEFT JOIN submission_stats s ON s.challenge_id = d.challenge_id
GROUP BY c.contest_id;
```

The output should look like this:

```
contest_id | hacker_id | name   | total_submissions | total_accepted_submissions | total_views | total_unique_views |
+------------+-----------+--------+-------------------+----------------------------+-------------+--------------------+
|      66406 |     17973 | Rose   |               111 |                         39 |         156 |                56 |
|      66556 |     79153 | Angela |                 0 |                          0 |          11 |                 10 |
|      94828 |     80275 | Frank  |               150 |                         38 |          41 |                15
```

But it's coming out like this:

```
contest_id | hacker_id | name   | total_submissions | total_accepted_submissions | total_views | total_unique_views |
+------------+-----------+--------+-------------------+----------------------------+-------------+--------------------+
|      66406 |     17973 | Rose   |               222 |                         78 |         238 |                122 |
|      66556 |     79153 | Angela |              NULL |                       NULL |          11 |                 10 |
|      94828 |     80275 | Frank  |               150 |                         38 |          82 |                 30
```

Tables schema:

[image]

Comment: Hi Andre - Thanks for the question! Would you be able to provide mimumum reproducible example in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7 or similar websites? - It could enable to get an answer faster. Also, it is recommended that you should not provide any details over image on the question (best practice is to share the details in text format on the question).

Comment: can you please include data related to `contest_id = 66406` and `hacker_id = 17973`. Your screenshots doesn't contain complete data regarding this. One more thing, due to one to many relationship for `submission_stats`, data would be duplicated for `view_stats` also vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## What happens

The problem is that `view_stats` and `submission_stats` have multiple rows per `challenge_id`.

The `JOIN`s in the query happen before the `GROUP BY` and the `SUM`. So imagine, the result set of your query without `GROUP BY` and `SUM`.

A simplified example would be:

```
ids table:

id
--
 1


x table:

id|vx
------
 1|11
 1|22


y table:

id|vy
------
 1| 1
```

The result of

```
SELECT ids.id, x.vx, y.vy
FROM ids
LEFT JOIN x on x.id = ids.id
LEFT JOIN y on y.id = ids.id;
```

would be

```
| id  | vx  | vy  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1   | 11  | 1   |
| 1   | 22  | 1   |
```

Mind the duplicate `1` in the `vy` column, although, in the original `y` table there is only one row. This happens because, for `id=1` there are two rows in table `x`. These are joined first, thereby also duplicating the rows of the `ids` table. Then `y` is joined to these already duplicated rows which duplicates the rows of `y` too. When `SUM`'ing and grouping, we end up with.

```
| id  | SUM(vy) |
| --- | ------- |
| 1   |       2 |
```

You can find a dbfiddle with the simplified example to play around [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7PymiaXxNvYJfG84SRVPFN/0).

## Solution

There are multiple ways to solve this. The most intuitive is to `GROUP` and `SUM` the rows of `view_stats` and `submission_stats` before joining them.

```
SELECT c.contest_id, c.hacker_id, c.name,
   SUM(s.total_submissions) as total_submissions,
   SUM(s.total_accepted_submissions) as total_accepted_submissions,
   SUM(v.total_views) as total_views,
   SUM(v.total_unique_views) as total_unique_views
FROM concursos c
JOIN faculdades f ON f.contest_id = c.contest_id
JOIN desafios d ON d.college_id = f.college_id
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT 
      challenge_id, 
      SUM(total_views) as total_views,
      SUM(total_unique_views) as total_unique_views
   FROM view_stats
   GROUP BY challenge_id
) v ON v.challenge_id = d.challenge_id
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT 
      challenge_id,
      SUM(total_submissions) as total_submissions,
      SUM(total_accepted_submissions) as total_accepted_submissions
   FROM submission_stats
   GROUP BY challenge_id
) s ON s.challenge_id = d.challenge_id
GROUP BY c.contest_id
# to output only rows with non zero sums
HAVING
   IFNULL(SUM(s.total_submissions), 0) <> 0
   OR IFNULL(SUM(s.total_accepted_submissions), 0) <> 0
   OR IFNULL(SUM(v.total_views), 0) <> 0
   OR IFNULL(SUM(v.total_unique_views), 0) <> 0;
```

Comment: Thank you Christian, I understand your reasoning. But the code above still doesn't work and I'm not able to identify the error. Below is the error you are giving: ```ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM submission_stats
   GROUP BY challenge_id
) s ON s.challenge_id = d.challen' at line 22```

Comment: @AndréAlexandreStella what doesn't work? Is there an error when you execute the code or do you get wrong results?

Comment: True, there was a comma too much on one line. I fixed the code in the answer.

Comment: Error while executing code. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iHrCpH2sm2uiBQJ5qhFjMd/0

Comment: Thanks for making the fiddle! I've verified it there and after removing the `,` it works.

Comment: Thanks, but can each ```contest_id``` be on a single line?

Comment: You mean only one line for each `contest_id`? This conflicts with the fact that you also output `hacker_id` and there are multiple different values of `hacker_id` per `contest_id`. So either you would have to get rid of `hacker_id` or decide which one to use per each `contest_id` (e.g. `min` or `max`). But it seems that MySQL accepts this ambiguity, so I've adjusted the code in my answer.

Comment: I forgot a detail that I am unable to resolve. How to make contest_id not appear in the result if all sums (total_views, total_unique_views, total_submissions, total_accepted_submissions) are zero? Example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dF4TNdsfRdVj6zsQTa5ocd/0

Comment: See my updated answer about suppressing rows with just 0/NULL.

Comment: Thank you very much!